# Invisible memory leak? - malloc and strcpy

Tags: c, memory

I compiled my code and the first two times it crashed. I didn't changed a thing and rage compiled again and the third and fourth compile process worked out well without any crashes.

The first two crashes didn't happen immediately, it had already printed my printf statement and immediately it was closed forcefully.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char testString[] = "Yiu Rules";
  char* destString = (char*)malloc(sizeof(strlen(testString))*2);

  strcpy(destString, testString);

  printf("%s", destString);

  free(destString);

  return 0;

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Whenever you encounter kind-of-esoteric errors on C code, it probably is a memory issue. [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html) is your friend in those cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You allocate `sizeof(strlen(testString)) * 2` bytes of memory. This does not seem to make sense. `sizeof(strlen(testString)) * 2` is `sizeof(size_t) * 2`, which is generally not enough for your string.

`sizeof(size_t) * 2` is typically either 16 or 8 bytes of memory on 64- or 32-bit platforms respectively. On 64-bit platform your code will "survive", since your string does fit into 16 bytes. But on a 32-bit platform it will not fit, it will overrun the allocated memory and damage the heap.

This

```
char* destString = malloc(strlen(testString) * 2);
```

would've made some sense (if you wanted to experiment with overallocating memory), but where that `sizeof` came from and why is not clear to me.

Comment: Oh, I'm pretty new to programing, I thought you always need the sizeof operator because from  a semantic point of view it would make sense to me. But thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @Yíu: You can use `sizeof` in there, e.g. `char* destString = malloc((strlen(testString) + 1) * sizeof *destString);`. But `sizeof(char)` is always 1, meaning that you can omit it as a multiplier. It is a matter of personal taste.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(strlen(testString))` is not what you think it is. You calculate the size in bytes of the value returned by `strlen` which is `size_t`.

Just use `strlen(testString)`.

That's why `strcpy` is not a safe function and you shall use `strncpy`.

Comment: You should not use `strncpy` with zero-terminated strings either. If you want a "safe" string copying function that would be `strlcpy` (which is unfortunately non-standard). But in general the whole idea of truncating strings when they don't fit in memory is rather questionable.

Comment: Ah, thanks your quick answer, appreciate :)

I guess for the moment I'm fine with strcpy, better get the basics right before going to advanced stuff.

Answer (score 0):

sizeof(strlen(testString)) is indeed incorrect but it nonetheless show a good practice which is the use of the sizeof operator applied to the type char. In your case you use sizeof on a size_t which isn't what you want, strlen already gives you the number of bytes you want to pass to malloc, but if you want to use sizeof aswell, here is a proper way to do so :

```
(char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(testString) * 2 + 1).
```

Pay attention to the + 1 at the end of the malloc: strlen doesn't count the terminating NULL byte of the string which it's computing the length of. Your strcpy may then work but you might aswell eventually get a bus error or some kind of error because you try to append a \0 (in the strcpy) to an unreserved portion of memory.

Moreover, your malloc may return you an already used area of memory (but it rarely happens in short programs like the one you provided) so you could make use of bzero just after the allocation to be sure you're working on a clean memory.